# How I make a table cell click takes me back to the "previous" view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have been searching similar questions regarding the usage of method didSelectRowAtIndexPath but I found that everyone just wants to create a new view and go to it when click on a table's cell.

In my case, I have tab bar view; on one of the tabs, there is a button that takes me to a table view. When I click on any cell of the table I need to go back to the caller tab view. How I do that?

Thanks,
Raafat

Comment: When you click's in your button,whick method are you using to load the UITableView page?Just loading a NIB or pushing a view with UINavigationContoller,other!

Comment: I use storyboard segue between the button on the tab bar view and the table view. What I want to achieve is to go back to the tab bar view when I select any cell in the table view.

Answer (score 2):

if you are pushing your view via UINavigationController then you can just simply do

```
    - (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

or if you want to switch to another tab in your UITabBarController, you can do something like this

```
      [myTabBarController setSelectedIndex:index]
```

Comment: Hi Diffy, My experience with iOS App programming is only few days old :-) Can you please explain more in simple language?

Comment: @RaafatSaid This answer is relatively straightforward; if you're having trouble understanding, you should consider doing some tutorials from Apple to get a better understanding of view controllers and views.